# RecyclerView content not using full width of fragment parent

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

So I have a recyclerview that is within a fragment and when the content is loaded into the recyclerview it does not occupy the full width of the screen. Weird thing is that i am using this code for another project practically the same and there are no issues.

The fragment layout is like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/windowBackground"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.dishesteam.dishes.activities.HomeActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator">

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/latest_recycler">

            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/add_dish_fab"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/trending_img"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_trending_up_black_24dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:text="Nothing here at the moment"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:id="@+id/empty_text"
    android:layout_below="@+id/trending_img"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="@color/ColorDarkGrey" />
```

The layout for the individual items of the recyceler is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/textColorPrimary"
app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="4dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/owner_image"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_account_circle_black_24dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/owner_text"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/owner_image"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/post_date"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_cake_black_24dp"
        android:id="@+id/first_dish_image"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/dish_name"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/dish_description"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_favorite_black_24dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:id="@+id/likes_btn"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:text="Favourite"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/likes_btn_text"
                android:textColor="@color/ColorDarkGrey" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_share_black_24dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:id="@+id/share_btn"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:text="Share"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/share_btn_text"
                android:textColor="@color/ColorDarkGrey" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_chat_bubble_black_24dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:id="@+id/comment_btn"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:text="Comment"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/comment_btn_text"
                android:textColor="@color/ColorDarkGrey" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and my create view method in the fragment is the following,
I am refactoring my code to use butterknife for view initilization and events.

```
   @BindView(R.id.empty_text)
TextView empty_text;

@BindView(R.id.trending_img)
ImageView trending_img;

private FloatingActionButton add_dish_fab;
private LatestDishesAdapter latestDishesAdapter;
private RecyclerView recycler_view;
private ArrayList<DishServer> dishes_list = new ArrayList<>();
private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeContainer;
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

private EventBus eventBus = EventBus.getDefault();

public static LatestFragment newInstance() {
    return new LatestFragment();
}

private Subscription subscription;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_latest, container, false);

    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

    add_dish_fab = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.add_dish_fab);
    add_dish_fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent add_dish_activity = new Intent( getActivity(), AddDishActivity.class);
            startActivity(add_dish_activity);
        }
    });

    recycler_view = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.latest_recycler);
    recycler_view.setHasFixedSize(true);

    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

    recycler_view.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener scrollListener = new EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(linearLayoutManager) {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount, RecyclerView view) {
            // Triggered only when new data needs to be appended to the list
            // Add whatever code is needed to append new items to the bottom of the list
            swipeContainer.setRefreshing(true);
            getLatest(totalItemsCount+15);
        }
    };

    recycler_view.addOnScrollListener(scrollListener);

    latestDishesAdapter = new LatestDishesAdapter(dishes_list, new LatestDishClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShareClick(DishServer dishServer) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCommentClick(DishServer dishServer) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DishActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Dish", dishServer.getDish());
            intent.putExtra("show_comments", "show_comments");
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLikeClick(DishServer dishServer) {
            addFav(dishServer.getDish().get_id());
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewDishClick() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProfileClick() {

        }
    });

    recycler_view.setAdapter(latestDishesAdapter);

    swipeContainer = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);

    swipeContainer.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {

        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            getLatest(15);
        }
    });
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getLatest(15);
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}
```

This is the result that does not occupy the full width of the screen

[image]

My Adapter code

```
 private List<DishServer> content = new ArrayList<>();
private LatestDishClickListener latestDishClickListener;

public LatestDishesAdapter(List<DishServer> content, LatestDishClickListener latestDishClickListener) {
    this.content = content;
    this.latestDishClickListener = latestDishClickListener;
}

@Override
public LatestDishesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.dish_item_layout, null);

    return new LatestDishesViewHolder(view);
}

public void setLatestDishes_list(@Nullable List<DishServer> dishes) {
    if(dishes==null){
        return;
    }
    this.content.clear();
    this.content.addAll(dishes);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void addToDishes(DishServer dishServer){
    if(dishServer==null){
        return;
    }

    content.add(dishServer);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(LatestDishesViewHolder holder, int position) {
    DishServer object = content.get(position);

    holder.bind(object, this.latestDishClickListener, position);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return content.size();
}
```

}

ViewHolder Code -

```
     private CircleImageView owner_image;
private TextView owner_text, post_date, dish_name, dish_description;
private ImageView dish_first_image;
private AppCompatImageButton likes_btn, share_btn, comments_btn;

public LatestDishesViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    owner_image = (CircleImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.owner_image);
    owner_text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.owner_text);
    post_date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_date);
    dish_name = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.dish_name);
    dish_description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dish_description);
    dish_first_image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.first_dish_image);

    likes_btn = (AppCompatImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.likes_btn);
    share_btn = (AppCompatImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.share_btn);
    comments_btn = (AppCompatImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_btn);
}

public void bind(final DishServer dishServer, final LatestDishClickListener latestDishClickListener, int position){
    if(dishServer.getOwner().getImage_url()!=null&&!dishServer.getOwner().getImage_url().isEmpty()){ //handle user image
        Glide.with(itemView.getContext())
                .load(R.string.image_base_url + dishServer.getOwner().getImage_url())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_account_circle_black_24dp)
                .into(this.owner_image);
    }

    if(!dishServer.getOwner().getFirstname().isEmpty()){
        owner_text.setText(dishServer.getOwner().getFirstname() +" "+dishServer.getOwner().getLastname());
    }

    dish_name.setText(dishServer.getDish().getName());
    dish_description.setText(dishServer.getDish().getDescription());

    if(!dishServer.getDish().getSteps().get(0).getImage().isEmpty()){ //handle user image
        Glide.with(itemView.getContext())
                .load(R.string.image_base_url + dishServer.getDish().getSteps().get(0).getImage())
                .centerCrop()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_cake_black_24dp)
                .into(this.dish_first_image);
    }

    likes_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            latestDishClickListener.onLikeClick(dishServer);
        }
    });

    share_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            latestDishClickListener.onShareClick(dishServer);
        }
    });

    comments_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            latestDishClickListener.onCommentClick(dishServer);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please add your adapter code

Comment: just edited my post adding the adapter code

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is in your `onCreateViewHolder`

```
@Override
public LatestDishesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.dish_item_layout, null);

return new LatestDishesViewHolder(view);
}
```

It is important here to *not* supply true, but do supply the parent:

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.dish_item_layout, parent, false);
```

Supplying the `parent` View lets the inflater know what `layoutParams` to use

Comment: let my try that out Ayush

Comment: If we supply `null` to `parent` and `false` to `attachToParent` then also this problem occurs. Thank you so much for the answers though.