# Why does my RecyclerView Layout width looks like its wrap content even though i put it match parent

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

so I have a recycler view layout that look like the image below. I set the width to match parent and in this layout it is like what I want it to be. So when I call this recycler layout to my home I want the view to be exactly like this.
 [Recycler Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvttZ.png)

but when I call the recycler view to my home layout and I try to run it why does it becomes like this? its like my width is wrap content. the width isn't full until the right side.

[My recycler view when I run the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ndbE.png)

here is my recyclerview layout xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">

   <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="72dp"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Plastik"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewCategory"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewTitle"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:text="Non Organik"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewPrice"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Price"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_medium"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

   </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And this is my Home Layout xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:theme="@style/HomeTheme"
    tools:context=".HomeFragment">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logog40w"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logog4w"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pohong4w"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/pohong4w"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_name"
            android:layout_width="85dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/pohong4w"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/logog40w" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/jemputrutin_status"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Status Penjemputan Rutin:"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pohong4w" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_home_jemputrutin_status"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="STATUS"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/jemputrutin_status"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/jemputrutin_status" />

        <LinearLayout

            android:id="@+id/layoutmainfeature"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/jemputrutin_status">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/jemput_rutin"
                android:layout_width="105dp"
                android:layout_height="135dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="51dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="51dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="8dp"

                    >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="90dp"
                        android:layout_height="90dp"
                        android:padding="4dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/g4w_jemputrutin" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="Jemput Rutin"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="12dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/antar_sendiri"
                android:layout_width="105dp"
                android:layout_height="135dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="51dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="51dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="8dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/img_antarsendiri"
                        android:layout_width="90dp"
                        android:layout_height="90dp"
                        android:padding="4dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/g4w_antarsendiri" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="Antar Sendiri"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="12dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/jemput_sekarang"
                android:layout_width="105dp"
                android:layout_height="135dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="51dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="51dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="8dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="90dp"
                        android:layout_height="90dp"
                        android:padding="4dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/g4w_jemputsekarang" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="Jemput Sekarang"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="11dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/recyler_title"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Harga Per Kg"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/layoutmainfeature" />


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recyler_title" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45308754/5575410)

Comment: change RecyclerView's "match_parent" to "0dp"

Comment: FWIW, You can't put a `RecyclerView` within a `NestedScrollView` going in the same direction and expect it to work - it'll inflate every View in your `RecyclerView` since a `NestedScrollView` has an infinite length. You need to make those other views part of your RecyclerView adapter (say, as another view type).

Answer (score 0):

remove these two lines from recycler view and try again

```
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent
```

which makes your recycler view part like this

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recyler_title" />
```

Comment: stil cannot. do u have any other solution ?